# showing calendar dynamic with also displaying month

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

here I used one label at top to display the today month with year. And also I have 6 label which will display the todays date like say 31dec to 5 Jan. Here is the code:

**This will display the todays date from next 5 date**

```
 NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel];
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
     NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:today options:nil];
     UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
     label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
 }
```

**This will display the current month with year**

```
// show the present month
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

   // NSDateFormatter *date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
    NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy";
    NSString * yearString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",monthString,yearString];
```

***Important:***

what I need is I need to display like below image:

[image]

1. The current date should display at last and should show previous 5 dates before.
2. I have two button at left and right. when ever user press right button like say now its 31Dec. And when user press right it should change to 1Jan and should display the previous 5 date from Jan 1. And also the month .label should automatically change to Jan,2016.  Like below image:

[image]

Two button action:

```
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:-1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
}
```

This code I did for changing only month I tried. But no changing my date label.

Please explain me in code.

**Full Edited:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDate *firstLabelDate = [NSDate date]; //make it class variable

    NSDate *lastLabelDate = [NSDate date]; //make it class variable

    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel]; //make it class variable

    [self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:YES andFromDay:self.lastLabelDate];
}


- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    [self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:YES andFromDay:self.lastLabelDate];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:-1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    [self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:NO andFromDay:self.firstLabelDate];
}

- (void)updateDateLabelsGoingForward:(BOOL) goForward andFromDay:(NSDate*) dayFrom {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        int dateToBeModified = goForward?1:-1;
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:dateToBeModified toDate:dayFrom options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)self.labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

        if(i==5){
            self.lastLabelDate = nextDate;
        }
        if(i==0){
            self.firstLabelDate = nextDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show me the code that you have written for the arrow button pressed event, can help you.

Comment: I use some action that will change only my month name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define one Date object globally  `NSDate *firstdate;` and assign its value in viewDidLoad  firstdate = [NSDate date];

now use following method to show your dates & month call this method from viewDidLoad `[self dateChange];`

```
-(void)dateChange
{
    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:firstdate options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
        if (i==5) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
            NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate] capitalizedString];
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy";
            NSString * yearString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate] capitalizedString];
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",monthString,yearString];
        }
    }

}
```

now set your calRight and calLeft as bellow

```
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {
firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
[self dateChange];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {
    firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];
}
```

Comment: if i open tomorrow my label will show 1Jan,Then my month label will automatically change to Jan, 2016

Comment: sorry but not getting you.

Comment: When i open my app todays date that is `31 dec` will show as first followed by next `5 date`. so that time my `datelabel.text `will be `Dec,2015`. So if i open my app on tomorrow the date will change to `1Jan`. So that time as per your code, Does my `Datlabel.text` will change to `Jan,2016`

Comment: DATES are changing when i press both button. But When i open my month is still  in Jan. Todays date is 31Dec So its should show Dec only know. So when i change to Jan 1 It should show jan. But in your solution its still in Jan. Not changing to any month

Comment: because month label is depend on last date show in dates label so for only first time if you want to show month as current date then you can wrire code after calling [self dateChange]; in viewdidload like that `NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
 dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99380/discussion-between-ios-learner-and-user5513630).

Comment: ...Please tell me to change the format of December,2015 to Dec,2015

Comment: please answer for this post if you can.. its same question what you gave the solution   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547354/about-disable-button-and-showing-date?noredirect=1#comment56836800_34547354

Answer (score 1):

1. First create an array which will store date's for 6 days...`NSArray *dates`.
2. Then initialise it with `[NSDate date]` at `dates[0]`.
3. Use `NSDateComponents` and subtract the date component and store the previous 5 days in the array from `dates[1.....4]`.
4. On click of the button you can increment or decrement the entire array and display the dates all again....

Comment: i am new to ios. Please explain me in code. This is my first time dealing with NSDate and all

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple actually you are almost there, add one more variable that will hold the last date displayed in the last label, let us not mess up by taking the date out of the label via NSDateFormatter etc. long route!

```
 NSDate *firstLabelDate = [NSDate date]; //make it class variable

 NSDate *lastLabelDate = [NSDate date]; //make it class variable

 NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel]; //make it class variable

[self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:YES andFromDay:self.lastLabelDate];
```

And your button actions should be modified as below,

```
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    [self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:YES andFromDay:self.lastLabelDate];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:-1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    [self updateDateLabelsGoingForward:NO andFromDay:self.firstLabelDate]

}
```

Add a common method to reload your date labels.

```
- (void)updateDateLabelsGoingForward:(BOOL) goForward andFromDay:(NSDate*) dayFrom {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        int dateToBeModified = goForward?(1*i):(-1*i);
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:dateToBeModified toDate:dayFrom options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)self.labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

        if(i==5){
            self.lastLabelDate = nextDate;
        }
        if(i==0){
            self.firstLabelDate = nextDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, and this could help you in the longer run.

Comment: i am getting error for `lastlabeldate`how to create that??

Comment: please see my update post.that is full code what i am using

Comment: sorry your code is showing `1jan 1jan 1jan 1jan 1jan 1jan` if i press left button it showsing ` 31dec 31dec 31dec 31dec 31dec 31dec`.. And also my month label is not chaging

Comment: got it!! try the edited code now, missed a simple logic.